Blank screen when connecting via Keycloak
I'm developping a web app that uses Keycloak 22 as an authentificator.
Sometimes, when I try to connect, my screen stays absolutely blank. This happens before accessing the login page. If I refresh my tab, it stays blank.
When I remove my cookies, and retry, then, it works.
The issue is quite rare (I would say it happens approximately 2% of the time) and not easily reproducible, but it is extremely annoying for the users.
When it happens :

I have no logs in my Java App
I have the following messages in my web console

In the network tab, things look like this :

And finally, the cookies for that request are the following (the expiration dates are a dozen hours in the future) :

When I remove the PLAY_SESSION cookie and reload the page, everything works well.

It mainly happens using Chrome, but I suppose it is because our key users mainly use Chrome.
I cannot find any resource online that seems to describe this.
It may help you to know that my app use sbt, java, play2 and pac4j.
  "org.pac4j" %% "play-pac4j" % "6.0.1",
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-oidc" % "3.8.0",
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-http" % "3.8.0",
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-jwt" % "3.8.0"

play version : 2.6.20

Is it possible to provide a minimal reproducible example? Are you using scala? Java? Which version of play? Were you able to see something in the logs? Maybe a warning? The http status code? Some error in the console of the browser? Do you know if it always happens using the same browser? Operative system? With the provided context is a bit hard to understand where the problem could be located?

Maybe creating automated tests that simulate the behavior you detailed and run them frequently, some day, they could fail and you would be able to re run it and find the root cause or at least collect more info and understand better what is happening

Hi @GastónSchabas, thanks for your time. I understand I may have been a little low on details (I guess I was kind of frustrated). I have provided some more. I've lost the logs of the last time I had the error. I'll keep this post updated when I encounter the issue again.
